# Subsequence that is increasing or decreasing in a sequence of sets $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Blockquote

If $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} $ a sequence of sets, then there exist a subsequence $(A_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb N} $ that is increasing ( $B_n \subseteq B_{n+1}$) or decreasing ( $B_n \supseteq B_{n+1}$)?

Comment: Sorry, it's not strict.

Comment: @bof Thanks, for some reason I was in an alternate universe where set inclusion was a total ordering...

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $A_n = \{n\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.